# Dynamic buttons with dynamic command executes only last command tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to generate buttons randomly from A-Z and that will execute respective python files using `os.system('A.py')` when clicked. I used `random_alphabets = random.sample(range(1, 26), 5)` to generate the random numbers and executed a for loop to add the buttons dynamically like:

```
for i in self.random_alphabets:
    a_button = tk.Button(self,text=chr(i+64),command=lambda: os.system(str(chr(i+64))+".py"))
    a_button.grid(row=0,column=i)
```

When I run this GUI, only the last randomly generated file gets executed. Suppose the randomly generated alphabets are ['U', 'S', 'E', 'Q', 'O'], then when I click on any button, only the "O.py" gets executed.

How to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the current value, as the lambda closure will always only close over names, not their values. So a simple `lambda i=i: ...` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes it worked. But on a second note, the buttons are not loaded in the proper order. That is if the order is ['U', 'S', 'E', 'Q', 'O'], then the buttons in the GUI are not being added in the same order. How to make them in the same order?

Comment: That is a different question - it’s about the layout. And without a fully reproducible example it’s not possible to answer.